# Как передать значение переменной по ссылке

Tags: php

Ребят, а как передать значение переменной по ссылке в этом же файле. То есть у меня есть:

```
<a href="http://localhost/index.php?search=XXXX">'.$result[$j].'</a>
```

Топчусь на месте уже час ). Суть в том, что ссылкой у меня сейчас является сама строка вывода $result[j]. Надо, дополнительно, что бы переменной search присваивалась сама строка вывода $result[j] как значение. А переменная search уже используется дальше программой.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php примеры смотрите на странице.

Answer (score 2):

Олег если я правильно понял твой вопрос то ответ

```
echo '<a href="http://localhost/index.php?search='.$result['$j'].'">'.$result['$j'].'</a>';
```

А дальше принимаешь параметром GET на следующей странице

```
$result =　$_GET['search']；
$result = htmlspecialchars($result);
```

Последние 2ве строки на самом деле можно наверное объединить в 1ну но я пока не знаю как, сам учусь. Надеюсь камрады простят новичка и не заминусуют.

Comment: если очень нужно объединить, то что мешает? берешь - и объединяешь: $result = htmlspecialchars($_GET['search']);

Comment: как засчитать ваш ответ, Vitaliy как ответ? есть только голосовать). всё получилось. спасибо